# Eslint not showing warnings - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier

On my new project, ESLint is not outputting warnings like before, I'm using VSCode. If I have an unsed var somewhere in my code, it doesn't show the warning in the  terminal output anymore. Only in the problem tab.

[image]

[image]

Here's my eslint config file:

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "airbnb-typescript",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
      "Atomics": "readonly",
      "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
      },
      "ecmaVersion": 2018,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
      "react",
      "react-hooks",
      "@typescript-eslint",
      "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks":"error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "camelcase": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, {"extensions": [".tsx"]}],
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "no-unused-expressions": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      {
        "allowExpressions": true
      }
    ],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "semi":"off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

and Here is my package.json devDependencies:

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.2"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.2",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": "^5.0.8",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, did you able to find the solution?

Comment: I notice all the answers miss the point of your question.  I had a similar problem in my react project using vite, and ended up here in my search for a solution.  In the end I had to use another vite plugin `vite-plugin-checker` to get warnings and errors to show on the console.

Answer (score 9):

You can check if ESLint works correctly by directly invoking the command `./node_modules/.bin/eslint .`. This way you'll get more helpful error messages if there are any. Also, make sure to check if you have multiple configuration files. Have a look at [this ESLint Documentation page](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats) to make sure, your configuration is the only (or the one with the highest priority).

> If there are multiple configuration files in the same directory, ESLint will only use one. The priority order is as follows:
>
> 1. .eslintrc.js
> 2. .eslintrc.cjs
> 3. .eslintrc.yaml
> 4. .eslintrc.yml
> 5. .eslintrc.json
> 6. package.json

Comment: Mine was because of extending eslint:recommended

`extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'react-app',
    'react-app/jest',
  ]`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, for me was that in my `package.json` I had this esLint configuration missing:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
```

Probably removed it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**Some tips to get it work**

1. Check eslint extension, it should be installed and enabled.
2. Set these values in your VSCode configs `ctrl` + `,`:

```json
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true
```

3. Sometimes it requires restarting eslint server after config changes applied.

[image]

- Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `p` (⇧ ⌘ P) to open VSCode command palette menu
- Type `restart`
- Select ESLint: Restart ESLint Server

Or just restart VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed in my project all this eslint plugins:

```
"eslint": "^4.19.1" 
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0"
"eslint-import-resolver-babel-plugin-root-import": "^1.1.1"
"eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.9.0"
"eslint-loader": "^2.2.1"
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1"
"eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.15.1"
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0"
```

And I have this config in my .eslintrc.js

```
const PATHS = require('./../paths');
const rootImportRegex = '~/(components|chains|output-types|utilities)/';

module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      webpack: {
        config: `${PATHS.config}/webpack.base.js`
      }
    },
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  rules: {
    'max-len': [2, 120, 2],
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', { 'devDependencies': true }],
    'import/no-unresolved': ['error', { ignore: [rootImportRegex] }],
    'import/extensions': ['warning', 'ignorePackages']
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project started from a `Create React App` then it might happens because of the way React team implemented eslint in the `webpack.config.dev` file.

When your project is being built, it uses [eslint-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-webpack-plugin) to make sure that eslint error appears on your app as an overlay.

The problem is that in their default configuration they point eslint to a specific eslint configuration (`eslint-config-react-app/base` see )

```
        new ESLintPlugin({
          // Plugin options
          extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
          formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
          eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
          failOnError: !(isEnvDevelopment && emitErrorsAsWarnings),
          context: paths.appSrc,
          cache: true,
          cacheLocation: path.resolve(
            paths.appNodeModules,
            '.cache/.eslintcache'
          ),
          // ESLint class options
          cwd: paths.appPath,
          resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
          baseConfig: {
            extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app/base')], // <-- here
            rules: {
              ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
                'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'error',
              }),
            },
          },
        }),
```

I always use the eject option and after removing all the properties under `// ESLint class options`, the project started to look at my own eslint configuration file and everything went as expected.

I don't know why they set it like that tbh.